# Shortening margins in an overleaf file

Tags: margins

If you compile the below code in Overleaf you will see that in your screen (please see the attached picture).

I am wondering how to shrink the distances which I have highlighted with blue arrows?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{XX}
\author{Smith }
\date{October 2022}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle
\large

Dear

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the package `geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to modify the page margins. The margins are not unique to OverLeaf too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\title{XX}
\author{Smith }
\date{October 2022}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle
\large

Dear

\end{document}
```

[image]

Change `margin` to whatever value you like or use `top`, `bottom` etc from the documentation I linked.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I wanted! I'll accept your answer.

Comment: No problem, best of luck with your OverLeaf project.